# Video Encoding uses 100% of iGPU and video lags extensively

Tags: windows-10, video, video-encoding

When I play a video (youtube or local) it runs smooth until some time (seconds or minutes) were it starts to lag really heavy. At this time the GPU Usage goes up to 100% in Taskmanager caused by the process wich is video encoding.

```
CPU: AMD Ryzen 3200G (internal graphics)
Mainboard: MSI B450M Pro-Vdh Max
Ram: Crucial 8GB 2666Mhz

SSD and HDD have both the same problem.
```

I allready installed the newest graphic drivers, the recommended drivers from msi, did a reinstall of Windows 10 from USB-Stick. I tried several Video-Players but all had similar problems. I also did a RAM-Test and searched through the internet. Gaming and everything else works fine.

What else could be the reason for this? Is it possible that the processor is broken? All Components are brand new.

Thanks for any advice!